# Filename encoding for Windows and Linux

Tags: windows-7, linux, encoding, filenames

My laptop has dual boot systems, one is Windows 7, another is Arch Linux, they share a disk. And I downloaded some files into the shared disk in Arch Linux, whose filenames contain Chinese, Korean and Japanese characters.

After I boot into Win7, I find that those files on the shared disk got encoding problem with CJK characters, while English parts look just fine.

How to make those file's name shown correctly in both systems?

PS: I've tries `convmv -f utf8 -t gbk` in Arch Linux, but get an error says something like encoding does not contains some character.

Comment: There is no easy way.  Windows uses UTF16 (UCS2) encoding.   Linus typically uses UTF8.

Comment: I tried convmv -f utf8 -t utf16, it gives me `new filename "��." contains characters, which are not POSIX filesystem conform! This may result in data loss.` why would this happend?

Comment: @fpmurphy1 I copy the files into a usb stick in arch linux and then boot into win7, find that those file names are shown correctly. Would that be related with the format of the shared disk?

Comment: @fpmurphy it really depends on the file systems and not the OS, unless the FS doesn't specify an encoding. Windows filesystems like NTFS or exFAT require the use of UTF-16 and anyone who reads that partition must also use UTF-16. \@宇宙人 what FS are you using?